# How to change angular 8 title dynamically based on active route when there are params in the route

Tags: angular, routes, angular-material

I am using this technique to change my title based on my route changes

**App Component:**

```
this.router.events
  .filter((event) => event instanceof NavigationEnd)
  .map(() => this.activatedRoute)
  .map((route) => {
    while (route.firstChild) { route = route.firstChild; }
    return route;
  })
  .filter((route) => route.outlet === 'primary')
  .mergeMap((route) => route.data)
  .subscribe((event) => this.titleService.setTitle(event['title']));}
```

**App-Route:**

```
{
  path : '',
  redirectTo: 'home',
  pathMatch: 'full',
  data: {title: 'Home'}
```

}

And that is working fine, until i was trying to change the title from another component (because i needed to get the route param and set them as the title) and that did not work.

***Example:***

**HTML:**

```
 {
    path: 'products/:category/:id',
    component: DetailPageComponent,
  },
```

**Component:**

```
    this.route.params.subscribe((params) => {
  this.route.queryParams.forEach((queryParams) => {
    this.category = queryParams['type'];
    this.type = null;
    this.type = params['category'];

    if(this.category) {
      this.titleService.setTitle(this.category + '- Page');
    } else if (this.type) {
      this.titleService.setTitle(this.category + '- Page');
    }
```

So is there any way to be able to change the title from the component it self and keeping the ***data: {title: 'Home'}*** technique? or is there a way to get the category from the route and directly use it like ***data: {title: ':category'}*** ?

Comment: What if you don't set title in AppComponent if route data has no title set? that way if component has set title, it would stay?

Comment: Thanks man, i added a condition to check if the event['title'] exist before i set the title and that work like a charm XD

Comment: if you want post your comment as an answer to accept it :p

Comment: Thanks @Kardon63, glad that it worked :)